# Spring Boot - Reading Text File using ResourceLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I’m trying to read a text file using Spring resource loader like this :

```
Resource resource  = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:\\static\\Sample.txt");
```

The file locates  here in my Spring boot project:
[image]

It works fine when running the application in eclipse, but when I package the application then run it using java –jar , I get file not found exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/Sample.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the
 file system: jar:file:/C:/workspace-test/XXX/target/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/static/Sample.txt
```

I unziped the Jar file the Sample locates in :
XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\BOOT-INF\classes\static\Sample.txt

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to unzip your jar file to see where is your Sample.txt.Maybe is has been moved when you package.

Comment: I did it's here : XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\BOOT-INF\classes\static\Sample.txt

Comment: Please print the CLASSPATH variable on the shell and show the value. `echo %classpath%`.

Comment: got this ! :  %classpath%

Comment: So it is not set. How do you run your program. Show the full command.

Comment: java -jar target/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Can you try java -cp target/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar full.package.name.ClassName

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have checked your code.If you would like to load a file from classpath in a Spring Boot JAR, then you have to use the `resource.getInputStream()` rather than `resource.getFile()`.If you try to use `resource.getFile()` you will receive an error, because Spring tries to access a file system path, but it can not access a path in your JAR.

detail as below:

https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-classpath-spring-boot/

Answer (score 11):

Please try `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/Sample.txt");`

Working with this code when run with `java -jar XXXX.jar`

[image]

------ update ------

After go through your codes, the problem is you try to read the file by the `FileInputStream` but actually it's inside the jar file.

But actually you get the `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` so means you cat get the InputStream, so you can do it like `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream())).readLine();`

Comment: Did not work for me, perhaps bcs I'm using Spring Boot?

Comment: @Greg Yes, I'm using spring boot 1.4.3, what's the exact verion for you?

Comment: mine is 1.4.3.RELEASE, this is strange !

Comment: @Greg is this a clean spring boot project? did you change your spring boot profiles? and maybe you need to check your `Spring-Boot-Classes` in MANIFEST.MF file, like `Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/`

Comment: Yes, It's a brand new one and all are default configurations

Comment: @Greg interestiong, maybe you can push it to github, so I can get your codes and have a try.

Comment: it's a simple one, one controller and one service class

Comment: @Greg OK, the real problem is caused by `try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(resource.getFile())))`, actually `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/Sample.txt")` get the real resoruce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133599/discussion-between-liping-huang-and-greg).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and as @Gipple Lake explained, with Spring boot you need to load file as inputStream. So bellow I'll add my code as example, where I want to read import.xml file

```
public void init() {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("imports/imports.xml");
    try {
        InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
        try {
            document = readXml(dbAsStream);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                trace.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                trace.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        trace.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initListeImports();
    initNewImports();
}

public static Document readXml(InputStream is) throws SAXException, IOException,
      ParserConfigurationException {
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

      dbf.setValidating(false);
      dbf.setIgnoringComments(false);
      dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
      dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
      DocumentBuilder db = null;
      db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

      return db.parse(is);
  }
```

I added "`imports.xml`" bellow `src/main/ressources/imports`

Answer (score 3):

Put the files under **`resources/static`**, it will be in classpath and read the path like below

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static/pathtosomefile.txt");
resource.getURL().getPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69687770/8440358). Read the `ClassPathResource` and copy the content to a `String`.

```
try {
   ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("static/Sample.txt");
   byte[] data = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
   String content = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all file in folders

this is sample code.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("app/files")
public class FileDirController {
    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);

        Resource resources[] = new Resource[0];
        try {
            resources = resolver.getResources("files/*"); // src/main/resources/files
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (final Resource res : resources ) {
            System.out.println("resources" + res.getFilename());
        }


        modelAndView.setViewName("views/file_dir");

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if resource is present inside `resources/static/listings.csv`

`String path = "classpath:static/listings.csv";`

`ResultSet rs = new Csv().read(path, null, null);`