# Reading file available in resources folder with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I am going to read a file available in resources folder in my Springboot application. I have used ResourceLoader to do it. But I get a FileNotFoundException when I try to execute my application.

```
Error creating bean with name 'demoController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.graphql] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/home/dilan/Projects/demo/target/demo.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/schema.graphql
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Below is my Code

```
 @Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

final Resource fileResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:schema.graphql");
File schemaFile = fileResource.getFile();
TypeDefinitionRegistry definitionRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile);
RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
```

Can anybody please help me to sort this out

[image]

Comment: you're right .. it duplicates another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754712/spring-boot-reading-text-file-using-resourceloader Please try to even google one time before posting useless questions..

Comment: you cannot get file from a `jar`.. try fetch the file as stream..

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

Smth like this :

```
InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("schema.graphql").getInputStream();
```

Or

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("schema.graphql").getFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the code below to access files in ressources folder with spring boot

```
 File file = new ClassPathResource("schema.graphql").getFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69687770/8440358),
Accessing the `ClassPathResource` and copying the content to a `String`

```
try {
   ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("schema.graphql");
   byte[] data = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
   String content = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```