# How to file from resources folder in spring boot configuration class?

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, io, resources

this is the font file under fonts folder in resources:

[image]

now, i want to get this file and use in `CaptchaConfiguration` that is a spring configuration class, but cannot:

```
@Configuration
public class CaptchaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CaptchaService captchaService() {

        WordGenerator wordGen = new RandomWordGenerator("123456789");

        Font font;
        try {
            ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("fonts/iranSans.ttf");    
            File fontFile = new File(res.getPath());

            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        }

        // ....
    }
}
```

i also tested `File fontFile = new File(getClass().getResource("fonts/iranSans.ttf").getFile())`, but didn't have any result and `res` is null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754712/spring-boot-reading-text-file-using-resourceloader Maybe this helps

Comment: try this; `code`    File file = new ClassPathResource("logback.xml").getFile();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem at some point and I solved it like this:

`new File(Objects.requireNonNull(CLASSNAME.class.getResource( "/micross.ttf")).getFile())`

So I think you need to add a Backslash to the path: "/fonts/iranSans.ttf".