# File relative path is not taken in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, filereader

I have created json file inside resources dir in spring boot application. File path is like: **resources/recipe/recipe.json**
When i use relative path, it won't be taken by java compiler so i'll get this exception. 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: recipe/recipe.json (No such file or directory). 
But this path is identified by IDE. if i click the path, it will be redirected to json file. Can anyone tell what the issue is ?

(FYI: absolute path is working perfectly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the resources folder in your classpath, then you should use Spring's Resource classes and specify the resource location as

```
classpath:recipe/recipe.json
```

You probably want to read this answer:
[Spring Boot - Reading Text File using ResourceLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754712/spring-boot-reading-text-file-using-resourceloader)

Answer (score 0):

If your resouce is present inside `resources/static/listing.csv`

`String path = "classpath:static/listings.csv";`

`ResultSet rs = new Csv().read(path, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a file which is **not** in the classpath, you can provide the relative path from the root module directory.

E.g.

`new File("src/main/resouces/recipe/recipe.json");`