# Relative path doesn't work on the server - Spring Boot and Docker

Tags: spring-boot, file, filepath

I have a service (Spring Boot). One of my features is to read a docx file, replace some text and save on the clients computer.

I have a file skom.docx and locally I can without any problems find that file:

```
@Getter
public enum ReportTemplatesEnum {

    KANC("src/main/resources/templates/skom.docx");

    private final String path;
}

(...)
    File file = new File(reportData.getReportType().getPath()); --> the path from Enum
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
(...)
```

But when I deploy my service to the server (containerized in Docker) I get the error:
 Request: /odo/incident/generateOneReport/255 methodGET

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/main/resources/templates/skom.docx
>   (No such file or directory)

How to prepare the path to my files?
Locally works perfectly.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(reportData.getReportType().getPath());
                InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
                XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(dbAsStream);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - Reading Text File using ResourceLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754712/spring-boot-reading-text-file-using-resourceloader)

Comment: Yes, you're RIGHT! Solution: Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(reportData.getReportType().getPath());
    InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(dbAsStream);